# Recast: reset all memory except specific field

Tags: chatbot, sap-conversational-ai

Is there a way, while configuring recast bot, to set an action to reset all memory, except a specific field?

I already tried to unset all fields except the one I need, but it's boring, unextendable, unscalable and unmaintenable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should ask it on Recast.ai 's [GitHub issues](https://github.com/RecastAI/Recast.AI). Most of the time they respond within 24h.

Answer (score 0):

currently there is no way to unset all memory expect one specific field from the Builder but through the API you can send a new memory object with only the field you want to keep and this will erase the current memory - you can do this using a webhook call that has only this purpose.